# Adding values to two different NSMutableArray without increasing the retain count

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, memory-management

I have two simple NSMutableArray that consists of few objects. Some of these objects can be common but need to be stored in both of the arrays as uses of both arrays are defined for totally different purpose.

However, the problem is that after adding same objects to both array, on changing the value of one of the common object, does not reflect in 2nd array.

For example,

Let's say we have two mutable NSArray:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArrayOne;
NSMutableArray *mutableArrayTwo;
```

Now let's create the object definition that these array needs to contain.

```
@interface: DummyObject : NSObject
{
     int objectValue;
}

@property (nonatomic) int objectValue;

-(void) printObjectValue;

@end
```

Now let's create the base class to store the arrays.

**Base Class Definition**

```
@interface: BaseClass : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *mutableArrayOne;
    NSMutableArray *mutableArrayTwo;
}
-(void) init;
-(void) printBothArrays;

@end
```

**Base Class Implementation**

```
@implementation BaseClass

-(void) init
{
     // initialize the mutable array.
     mutableArrayOne = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapicity:5];
     mutableArrayTwo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapicity:5];

     DummyObject *dummyObject = [DummyObject alloc];
     [dummyObject setObjectValue:5];

     DummyObject *dummyObjectTwo = [DummyObject alloc];
     [dummyObjectTwo setObjectValue:2];

     [mutableArrayOne addObject:dummyObject];
     [mutableArrayOne addObject:dummyObjectTwo];

     [mutableArrayTwo addObject:dummyObjectTwo];

}

@end
```

Now let me the modify the DummyObject in array One:

```
for (DummyObject* dummyObject in mutableArrayOne)
{
    [dummyObject setValue:100]; 
}
```

**Problem**
Now here starts the problem when I am printing the values for both array objects:-

## Printing First Array

```
for (DummyObject* dummyObject in mutableArrayOne)
{
    [dummyObject printObjectValue]; 
}
```

**Output Log (from first array) **

```
100
100
```

## Printing second Array

```
for (DummyObject* dummyObject in mutableArrayTwo)
{
    [dummyObject printObjectValue]; 
}
```

**Output Log (from second array) **

```
2
```

So here we can see that MutableArray is keeping the copy of the object, however, I want to store only the reference. That means, on changing the value of the object in 1st array should reflect in 2nd array.

How can we do that? 
Do we any other alternative?

Thanks,
**Paras Mendiratta**

Comment: is there a typing address on the code example? the output from the first array returns 2 100s, and the one from the second returns 1 2. which means that you are adding 2 objects to the first array and 1 to the second, contrary to what your code says. (which makes me believe your spelling mistake is making you add them to the first array)

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed the sample code.

Comment: If your code is exactly like that, are you sure than when you print the second mutable array you are not gettin 100?

Comment: What happens if you initialize the dummy objects? `DummyObject *dummyObject = [[DummyObject alloc] init]`

Comment: +1 @LuisOscar , With this code, you should have got it as `100` in the second array too.

Comment: @codesnooker by the way, by default when a nsarray is created the objects are not copied, just the reference is created with pointers, hence its an array of object pointers, if you want the objects to be copied, then you can use the init with array and copy thingy. NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:someArray copyItems:YES];

Comment: @LuisOscar I think you are right. Looks like I have messed up somewhere in my code. The sample I provided is something I want to achieve; however original code is more complex as it having too many other attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will ideally work, seems like some issue with setting object.
For e.g. you can check like this -

```
NSMutableString *firstString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"first"];
NSMutableString *secondString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"second"];

NSMutableArray *originalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: firstString, secondString, nil];
NSMutableArray *copyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: firstString, secondString, nil];

[[copyArray objectAtIndex:0] appendString:@"add some text"];

for (int index = 0; index < [originalArray count]; index++) {
    NSLog(@"Original:%@ --- copy:%@", [originalArray objectAtIndex:index], [copyArray objectAtIndex:index]);
}
```

And output is -

```
2012-05-09 10:28:40.382 Demo[5237:f803] Original:firstadd some text --- copy:firstadd some text
2012-05-09 10:28:40.384 Demo[5237:f803] Original:second --- copy:second
```

EDIT - (Not adding object at the time of initialization)

```
NSMutableString *firstString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"first"];
NSMutableString *secondString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"second"];

NSMutableArray *originalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *copyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[originalArray addObject:firstString];
[copyArray addObject:firstString];

[originalArray addObject:secondString];
[copyArray addObject:secondString];

[[copyArray objectAtIndex:0] appendString:@"add some text"];

for (int index = 0; index < [originalArray count]; index++) {
    NSLog(@"Original:%@ --- copy:%@", [originalArray objectAtIndex:index], [copyArray objectAtIndex:index]);
}
```

Output -

```
2012-05-09 11:11:18.275 Demo[5433:f803] Original:firstadd some text --- copy:firstadd some text
2012-05-09 11:11:18.277 Demo[5433:f803] Original:second --- copy:second
```

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot set the objects at initialization of the arrays. Objects are creating at runtime on user actions. So I need to add the objects at runtime only.

Comment: Why don't you try to addObject on originalArray and copyArray after init. And then try to modify the object in one of the array and print the results. Results won't be same. :(

Comment: @codesnooker - still the same result, is setValue is your custom method?

Comment: I checked your code and it works well. Looks like I messed up somewhere in my original code. Not able to figure out the problem in the original. But thanks for you solution. I will dig my code.